# C# Asp.Net MVC Inheriting Abstract Class Methods On An Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, abstract-class, autofac

I have an abstract class, an interface, and a class that inherits both the abstract class and the interface.

I want to expose the method from the abstract class on the inheriting class. How do I achieve this?

```
public abstract class CustomerServiceBase
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "John Doe";
    }
}

public interface ICustomerService
{
    void DoOtherStuff();
}

public class CustomerService : CustomerServiceBase, ICustomerService
{
    public void DoOtherStuff()
    {
        //Code removed for brevity
    }
}

public class Start
{
    public void Go()
    {
        ICustomerService _customerService = new CustomerService();
        _customerService.DoOtherStuff();
        var name = _customerService.GetName();//This won't compile
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Apologies, I've added the additional code that accurately shows this scenario, i.e. Using Autofac for dependency injection into an Asp.Net MVC controller, and then using the service class to perform tasks.

```
public abstract class CustomerServiceBase
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "John Doe";
    }
}

public interface ICustomerService
{
    void DoOtherStuff();
}

public class CustomerService : CustomerServiceBase, ICustomerService
{
    public void DoOtherStuff()
    {
        //Code removed for brevity
    }
}

public static class AutofacConfig
{
    public static IContainer Register(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        ConfigureServices(builder);

        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

        SetBothDependencyResolvers(container);

        return container;
    }

    public static void ConfigureServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<CustomerService>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }

}

public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    protected readonly ICustomerService _customerService;

    public CustomerController(ICustomerService customerService)
    {
        this._customerService = customerService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        _customerService.DoOtherStuff();
        var name = _customerService.GetName();

        return View();
    }
}
```

**RESULT (based on the accepted answer)**

```
public abstract class CustomerServiceBase : ICustomerService
{
    public abstract void DoOtherStuff();

    //You could mark this as virtual if you want the option to override functionality
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "John Doe";
    }
}

public interface ICustomerService
{
    void DoOtherStuff();
    string GetName();
}

public class CustomerService : CustomerServiceBase
{
    public override void DoOtherStuff()
    {
        //Code removed for brevity
    }
}

public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    protected readonly ICustomerService _customerService;

    public CustomerController(ICustomerService customerService)
    {
        this._customerService = customerService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        _customerService.DoOtherStuff();
        var name = _customerService.GetName();

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: `GetName()` is a member of `CustomerServiceBase`, but your `_customerService` is an instance of your interface. Your interface doesn't know anything about the `CustomerServiceBase` class so compiler will complain. Why don't you want to move the method to the interface?

Comment: How would an `ICustomerService` know about _anything_ in `CustomerServiceBase`?  They aren't related at all

Comment: `//This won't compile` <= why would you expect it to?

Comment: Apologies, please see my update regarding the dependency on Autofac, I should have put that in to begin with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that your `_customerService` variable is of type `ICustomerService`.  Your interface does not know *anything* about your abstract class.  If you want something of that type to have a specific method, you need to *add* it to your interface:

```
public interface ICustomerService
{
    void DoOtherStuff();
    string GetName();
}
```

Then I would make your abstract class *implement* the interface, instead of your `CustomerService` class.  You will also need to add an `abstract` method in your abstract class so that way any classes that inherit from your abstract `CustomerServiceBase` will be *forced* to add a `DoOtherStuff()` implementation (and your abstract class does not have to add its own implementation):

```
public abstract class CustomerServiceBase : ICustomerService
{
    //abstract forces any inheriting class to implement 'DoOtherStuff' there
    public abstract void DoOtherStuff();

    //You could mark this as virtual if you want the option to override functionality
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "John Doe";
    }
}
```

And `CustomerService` should be:

```
public class CustomerService : CustomerServiceBase
```

Once you do that your `Index()` method will be just fine:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //DoOtherStuff() and GetName() are both part of the interface now
    _customerService.DoOtherStuff();
    var name = _customerService.GetName();

    return View();
}
```

Comment: @Igor true, I guess I should have addressed that creating the dependency (`new ...()`) was a bad idea.  You are correct in saying there isnt much to go on in the question

Comment: @Goober I made a small edit based on your editing of the question.  Now we should be in sync :)

Answer (score 3):

Just change the type of the variable. You'll still be able to call the members of ICustomerService since the class implements it.

```
public void Go()
{
    CustomerService _customerService = new CustomerService();
    _customerService.DoOtherStuff();
    var name = _customerService.GetName();
}
```

Comment: I'm using Autofac dependency injection so I'm bound to using the interface when instantiating the service from what i gather?

Comment: @Goober If you're using Autofac, then why are you saying `new ...`?

Comment: @KennethK. I was trying to provide a summary example, which was clearly incorrect. Apologies, please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to expose the method from the abstract class on the inheriting class. How do I achieve this?

This already occurs. The reason you are getting a compiler error is that the code you have specifies `_customerService` as type (interface) `ICustomerService` and this interface has no definition for method `DoOtherStuff()`. If you were to use type `CustomerService` instead then you could call methods defined on the abstract class that this type inherits from (or interfaces it implements).

```
CustomerService _customerService = new CustomerService();
_customerService.DoOtherStuff();
var name = _customerService.GetName(); // compiles just fine
```

---

As for the title of the question:

> Inheriting Abstract Class Methods On An Interface

That is not possible (in c#). Interfaces can extend other interfaces and be implemented by classes but a an interface cannot "inherit" from anything other than another interface (although the accepted vernacular is "extending" an interface).

Answer (score 0):

Use `CustomerService` instead of `ICustomerService` in `Go` method.

```
CustomerService _customerService = new CustomerService();
_customerService.DoOtherStuff();
var name = _customerService.GetName(); // Compiles now
```

Comment: What's the point of defining an interface if you're not going to use it?

Comment: It could be used elsewhere, not in a Go method.

Comment: Now `GetName` compiles, but not `DoOtherStuff` as `CustomerServiceBase` doesn't implement `ICustomerService`

Answer (score 0):

When you do `ICustomerService _customerService`
you are initiating to ICustomerService contract and its contract doesn't have anything called as `GetName()`

So either you get that on contract placing `GetName()` or create `CustomerService` itself as mentioned on above.

Further the whole idea of abstract class is interaction, so basically when you define `CustomerService` as NOT abstract class its fine to use

`CustomerService customerService = new CustomerService`

But instead of `CustomerService` better naming would be `PhoneService` or `TextService` coz these are things that Customer would directly interact to in real life. And use `CustomerService` itself instead of `CustomerServiceBase` coz people will use Customer Service but not directly but in the form of above mentioned Phone or Text or some other services.

```
public abstract class CustomerService {} <-- Think in real life this doesnt have interaction
public class PhoneService() {} <-- This interacts directly
```

Comment: "//But instead of CustomerService better naming would be PhoneService or TextService" - Thanks, it's actually a wrapper around Stripes DotNet Api, but I was providing a simple use case, specifically for the example...